# ZF2 architecture. modules or separate projects for api, admin, client ect

Tags: php, architecture, zend-framework2, structure

I am developing project witch has console logic, restfull API, admin and client websites.

I have started building all of them in single ZF2 application. I am using Application module for client website and console logic, API module for API and Admin module for admin website. And then I have started writing unit tests I realized that then I am calling some part of my code every module is being loaded (for example when I am calling console script witch only works with emails via IMAP my api documentation tool swagger is printing warnings about no server name).

I think this should decrease app performance and changing one part can break another. And also all parts are really diferent(Console, Restfull, and html output. different plugins, vendors ect.).

And now I think how can I solve this problem. I would like to keep the structure:`http://mysite/api` for API, `http://mysite/admin` for admin, `http://mysite/` for client site and `php index.php action` for console scripts.

How I should solve this problem? Should I split all those parts to separate ZF2 applications, or should I use same project but, some different autoloader. Or maybe there is some other good practices?

Answer (score 0):

Don't rearchitect your whole application to fix a performance problem you think might exist. The module bootstrap overhead for ZF2 is quite low. If your modules really have no dependencies on each other at all, try benchmarking your application as a baseline, then try disabling one module to see what difference it makes. If it doesn't make much difference, I'd keep it as it is.

Comment: thank you for your opinion. Yes performance is not the biggest issue with current service architecture. I am running into configuration issues. For example I changed API/module.php to return json errors, and later I found out that website errors are also returned in json. I would like to call each module only then it is needed. Maybe there is a way to create dependency between loaded modules and routes (example: I have swagger module which is loaded on every action and it is used only when documentation is being viewed)?

Comment: You can't conditionally load modules depending on the matched route, as routes are stored in modules (so the modules all need to be loaded to get the routes in the first place). If your modules really are completely separate then perhaps they should be separate apps, but you're the best person to be able to judge this.